# How can I cut only some lines, while leaving others unprocessed?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, scripting

I want to tail a log file that has a format similar to

```
Mar 22 23:26:18.793031 localhost my_process[1123]: (my_id) contents of actual log output
Mar 22 23:26:18.946769 localhost my_process[1123]: (my_id) more singe line contents
Mar 22 23:26:18.955423 localhost my_process[1123]: (my_id) 
****
* this log statement has a bunch of lines
****
```

I want to cut a lot of the junk out of these lines so that they aren't so long. However, I only want to cut the lines that start with the date etc, while leaving other lines alone. It should look something like:

```
23:26:18 my_process[1123]: contents of actual log output
23:26:18 my_process[1123]: more singe line contents
23:26:18 my_process[1123]:  
****
* this log statement has a bunch of lines
****
```

This is the pipeline I have going, but it is cutting all lines.

```
# first cut out the unwanted fields
# then cut out the unwanted decimal part of the timestamp
tail -f mylog.txt | cut -d " " -f 3,5,7- | cut -c 1-8,16-
```

Is there a way I could look for the lines that don't begin with that common date pattern and just let those lines through unprocessed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use awk like this:

```
awk '/ [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/{
   split($0, a, /: \([^)]+\) /)
   sub(/\.[0-9]+/, "", $3)
   print $3, $5, a[2]
   next
} 1' file.log

23:26:18 my_process[1123]: contents of actual log output
23:26:18 my_process[1123]: more singe line contents
23:26:18 my_process[1123]:
****
* this log statement has a bunch of lines
****
```

`/ [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/` will search for a specific pattern with `hh:mm:ss` in input line and parse those lines only. Rest of the lines will be printed as is.